# new keyword c# for method returning diff objects

Tags: c#

i have the following method inheritance

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntityModel> : IRepository<TEntityModel>
    where TEntityModel : Entity
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntityModel> GetAll()
    {

    }

}

public class Repository<TDomainModel, TEntityModel> : RepositoryBase<TEntityModel>, IRepository<TEntityModel>
    where TEntityModel : Entity
{
    public override IEnumerable<TDomainModel> GetAll() // --> the compiler complain to add "new" keyword, why ?
    {

    }
}
```

i know the method signature is the same but they both are returning two diff objects, so why the compiler complains about applying a "new" keyword on the GetAll method in Repository class ?

and if the above method is getting complained by the compiler the why the following is not required to apply "new" keyword ?

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntityModel> : IRepository<TEntityModel>
    where TEntityModel : Entity
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod(TEntityModel model)
    {

    }

}

public class Repository<TDomainModel, TEntityModel> : RepositoryBase<TEntityModel>, IRepository<TEntityModel>
    where TEntityModel : Entity
{
    public override void SomeMethod(TDomainModel model) // --> this one needs no "new" keyword
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't override a method with the wrong return type.

Comment: You mean "I know the method signature is *not* the same", right? The compiler wants you to be explicit in your intentions: the new method is *not* overriding the old one because its signature doesn't match.

Comment: And how is it supposed to guess which one to call if they have the same signature? Why don't you want to add `new`?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova...    simple, why can't the compiler figure it out based on the return object ?

Comment: @bet what if you'll write `var all= entity.GetAll();`? It can figure out the right one based on the type of `entity` though

Comment: Return type is not part of the method signature.

Comment: @Slaks..   "the wrong return type" --> I dont understand, pls explain !

Comment: you are overriding a method. Meaning you can ONLY override the body, not anything else.

Comment: @Michael..   it does not matter whether you are overriding it or not..  the compiler will still complain about the "new" keyword

Comment: yes because it will never know which method to actually call. return type does not make methods different.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you cannot change the return type of the base method.

E.g. this should work:

```
public override IEnumerable<TEntityModel> GetAll()
```

I guess there is no way to tell the Compiler that the return is covariant.

Can i ask what are you trying to achieve with TDOmainModel and TEntityModel and something like this won't fit the bill? Why you need them as separate generics?

```
public class RepositoryNew<TDomainModel> : RepositoryBase<TDomainModel>
    where TDomainModel : Entity
{
    public override IEnumerable<TDomainModel> GetAll() // --> the compiler complain to add "new" keyword, why ?
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT** This works for me:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntityModel> : IEntityRepository<TEntityModel>
where TEntityModel : Entity
{
    public IEnumerable<TEntityModel> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Repository<TDomainModel, TEntityModel> : RepositoryBase<TEntityModel>, IDomainRepository<TDomainModel>
    where TEntityModel : Entity
{
    public new IEnumerable<TDomainModel> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        var repository = new Repository<Domain, Entity>();

        IEntityRepository<Entity> entityRepo = repository; // IMPORTANT! Casting to IEntityRepository
        IDomainRepository<Domain> domainRepo = repository; // IMPORTANT! Casting to IDomainRepository

        IEnumerable<Entity> entityModels = entityRepo.GetAll();
        IEnumerable<Domain> domainModels = domainRepo.GetAll();

        RepositoryBase<Entity> repository2 = new RepositoryBase<Entity>();

        IEnumerable<Entity> entityModels2 = repository2.GetAll();
```

- Option 1 - Domain does not inherit from Entity:

  mark the method as a `new` method as they are returning completely different types :|
- Option 2 - if Domain : Entity:

  `RepositoryBase<TDomainModel>`
- Option 3 - Domain : Entity and you need the base Entity generic type, although you would be better to use Domain

  `public class RepositoryBase<TDomainModel, TEntityModel>`

Comment: @michael..   two generic classes..  one is to retrieve the data straight using entity models.  And another generic is to do mapping from entity to domain model.

Comment: Then `RepositoryBase` should take `TDomainModel` as one of its types too and you need to  have the base class declared as `public virtual IEnumerable<TDomainModel> GetAll()`. You can't change the type when you override.

Comment: @bet And what are you trying to achieve in the base class that you need a virtual GetAll? Can you post some code of what you expect the base class to do, and why you would want to override (non-compilable is fine)

Comment: What about making the base GetAll protected?

Comment: @MichalCiechan..  we some client applications...     some of them need to be able to use the RepositoryBase class to retrieve the records directly..   but some of the client applications also need to be able to pass the domain model (without having the knowledge about the entities) so that we have the Repository to do the mapping from domain to entity model.

Comment: @MichalCiechan.. you just don't get it, do you?  i know "new" keyword could be the answer..  but WHY do i need to add "new" keyword?  WHY the compiler complains to add "new" keyword? as per my original question.

Comment: because you cannot OVERRIDE a method and change its return type.

Comment: and there is no way to tell the compiler the return type is covariant (that you are returning a more derived class)

Comment: And if you are not returning a more derived class, then you have to specify new as its a completely different class